GDPR: ETH addresses and token transfers
How to ensure that your application is GDPR compliance when using wallet addresessee for your users (generally linking each user to one Ethereum Wallet Addresses), knowing that ERC-20 transfers will be easily traceable on public blockchains?
You also have different token standards focused on securities (ERC-1400, ERC-3643) but you have the same problems in terms of privacy: All transfers are easily traceable. Once you discover one user’s addresses, you will be able to track his balance and all transactions related to him.
What is the most accepted approach?
I have read about ZK-Proofs with SNARKS, but Zokrates (the most developed framework for that) is not production ready.
ZK Proofs also present a lot of limitations if you want different wallet addresses to interact between them, trough Smart Contracts, making DeFi like processes almost impossible.
I know that I could achieve similar results using a private Blockchain like Hyperledger Besu, but then I would not have any interoperability with other DeFi platforms.
My goal is to achieve GDPR compliant privacy in public EVM blockchains.
